# Copying column that have NaN value in it and adding prefix

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

I have x number of columns that contain NaN value

With the following code i can check that

```
for index,value in df.iteritems():

   if value.isnull().values.any() == True:
```

this will show me with Boolean values which volumns have NaN.

If true I need to create new column that will have prefix 'Interpolation' + name of that column in its name.
So to make it clear if Column with the name 'XXX' has NaN I need to create new column with the name 'Interpolation XXX'. 
Any ides how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame({'XXX':[1,2,np.nan,4], 'YYY':[1,2,3,4], 'ZZZ':[1,np.nan, np.nan, 4]})                                                                                                            

In [81]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[81]: 
   XXX  YYY  ZZZ
0  1.0    1  1.0
1  2.0    2  NaN
2  NaN    3  NaN
3  4.0    4  4.0

In [92]: nan_cols = df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist() 
In [94]: for col in df.columns: 
    ...:     if col in nan_cols: 
    ...:         df['Interpolation ' + col ] = df[col] 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [95]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[95]: 
   XXX  YYY  ZZZ  Interpolation XXX  Interpolation ZZZ
0  1.0    1  1.0                1.0                1.0
1  2.0    2  NaN                2.0                NaN
2  NaN    3  NaN                NaN                NaN
3  4.0    4  4.0                4.0                4.0
```